# Mobile site shows users’ total reputation rather than interval reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, mobile-web, users

If I go to the mobile site and sort users by reputation by month or other intervals, the page shows their *total* reputation numbers, rather than their reputation numbers during the *interval*.

[image]

The desktop site doesn’t have this problem.

[image]

Comment: Ooh I didn’t know there were more than `m` images @Sonic! That’s nice.